# UWP - Background task - short interval

Tags: uwp, dispatcher, background-task, suspend

I'm developing UWP application and I need to send my location every 15 sec if current state of application is active or suspended. I have tried two different approaches:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            await UpdateMethod(data);
        });
```

and

```
var taskResult = await backgroundTrigger.RequestAsync(taskParameters);
```

1. ExtendedExecution

   - works fine when application is active
   - when app is suspended Dispatcher is not available
2. ExtendedExecution + Background Task + Application Trigger

   - it works fine when app is active
   - when app is suspended I keep getting ApplicationTriggerResult.DisabledByPolicy after calling method above

Answer (score 2):

> when app is suspended Dispatcher is not available

I tested the [ExtendedExecution](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution) official sample on my side, `Dispatcher` worked well after suspending the app if the [`ExtendedExecutionSession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.extendedexecution.extendedexecutionsession.aspx) has been requested successfully. My environment is windows 10 build 14393 and I tested this feature on a PC device.

> I need to send my location every 15 sec

For your requirements, the `LocationTracking` [ExtendedExecutionReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.extendedexecution.extendedexecutionreason.aspx) is recommended for using. The [scenario 3](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cs/Scenario3_LocationTrackingReason.xaml) of the official sample has implemented the same feature as what you want, you can reference.

> when app is suspended I keep getting ApplicationTriggerResult.DisabledByPolicy after calling method above

According to the official sample, `ExtendExcution` already meet your requirements. For [application trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger), as far as I known, it cannot be requested out the UI thread.

Additionally, `ExtendExcution` can keep your app running for extra 10 minutes after suspending operation if no power connected for the device. More details please reference [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B817).

Comment: `private async void Sync(object sync)

        {

            var data = sync as string;

            if (data != null)
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    await _dl.UpdateLocation(data); // breakpoint at this line never gets hit
                });
            }
` 

Tried on 2 tablets, PC (10586 & 14393) and this doesn't work. I'm using 
        ExtendedExecutionReason.LocationTracking.

Comment: @lijevosmetalo I tested the official sample on 14393, it does work. Please also test the scenario 3 and following the official sample to correct your code. I cannot help resolve your issue by only one code line. If you still have issues please upload the whole reproduce project to let us help you.

Comment: Offical sample doesn't work for me. Try Scenario 3 and put the breakpoint at line 140 (or any line that between 140 and 159). Start the scenario, and then suspend application from VS. Scenario 1 which doesn't use Dispatcher in OnTimer method works fine, and Scenario 3 doesn't.

Comment: @lijevosmetalo if you tried the official sample on a different machine you can got same exception?

Comment: Hi, no I can't get any exception. Also, Scenario 3 works in one thrid of situations, and it NEVER works when i press the power button on my tablet or switch to non-UWP application.